# FFMPEG capture image from different video formats

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract image from video exactly at 5th second using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -deinterlace -an -ss 5 -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s 200x180 output.jpg 2>&1
```

It works for mp4 only where for other file formats i am getting a 0 kb image file.
Any helps,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your command works fine. Probably the length of the video you are using may have a less value than the time you specify with `ss` or `t`. Simply try this.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -ss 00:00:05 -vframes 1 out_image
```

It's worth reading [documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video).

Comment: Hi Chamath ,
Thanks for your help.Need another info as well i need ffmpeg command that converts any video format to mp4
i am using "ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4" its working fine, but sometimes that video plays as blank grey any help?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input_video -acodec libfaac -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 output_video`
remember to accept the answer if it works for you :D